# Why shm_open() succeeds even there is no /dev/shm?

Tags: linux, ipc, shared-memory

There is no /dev/shm in my Linux machine (I manually unmounted and removed it), but when I try shm_open() in my application, like `shm_open("foo", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);`, it still succeeds and returns 3 as the fd. So in this case where is the shared memory created? Can it still be **shared** with other processes?

And in this case why does `shm_open` only succeed when it runs as root user but fail as any non-root users?

Comment: It didn't give an error with `errno` set to `EINVAL`? The name argument is supposed to start with a `/` as the first character.

Comment: @Shawn No, it just succeeded and did not give any error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Trying `shm_open` in a chroot with no `/dev/shm` fails and returns -1 with `ENOSYS`, as expected. There's something else messed up with your program or setup. Please edit your exact kernel, glibc version and distribution in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`shm_open` creates a shared memory object if it doesn't exist.

Your `fd` should be a valid file descriptor you may use with `mmap` to share this memory area with other processes.

---

When you unmounted and "removed" the `/dev/shm` mount point, nothing changed really. It only serves as an access point to have a RAM-based filesystem.

Comment: So even there is no `/dev/shm`, we can still use `shm_open` and `mmap` to do inter-process communication, right? If so, I am wondering why we need `/dev/shm` at all.

Comment: Right. I've just added a short explanation. Basically `/dev/shm` is just a handle so that you could have a filesystem on RAM.

Comment: Do you know why `shm_open` only succeeds when it runs as root user but fails as any non-root users? If `/dev/shm` exists, any users can call `shm_open` to create shared memory successfully.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/4290aed05135ae4c0272006442d147f2155e70d7/NEWS#L892-L895

It seems that glibc<2.34 will search among the system's mount points for a suitable replacement if /dev/shm is not available.